# Exact (accurate) and cheapest Second Signal Generator circuit

Tags: clock, generator

Sorry, this is my first question.

I want to create a watch (clock) with needles, but I want to create a circuit to generate the second signal (not labview, not software).
I need to know the IC's needed for this and circuit.

Now, I was working long time ago (with TTL), I need something most recent electronic devices.
I was working with BCD and "7 Segment LED", now I don't know ...

---

I was thinking something like:
http://www.bowdenshobbycircuits.info/page11.htm

But if you have other proposal...

Comment: There are a few "standard clocks" GPS and WWVB.. Is that OK or do you want to make your own clock... much harder

Comment: Would a few counters and a 555 timer be adequate? How accurate do you want the clock to be?

Comment: Response 2 Thank you, My clock must work at least 1 year

Comment: Working for a year doesn't say much. How accurate does it need to be over a one year period? 1 minute? 1 second? 1 millisecond?

Comment: Response 1, George Herold, if you have link please let me know.

Comment: Only I want similar performance like this:
http://www.josepino.com/electronics/one_second_timebase
But for production is expensive to use this method.

Comment: You still haven't said how much accuracy you need over 1 year. This is important.

Comment: Sure, how much accuracy you need it's 1 Second.

Comment: I was thinking in a circuit  based in an oscillator.

Comment: "It's 1 second" is not an answer on accuracy. You want a 1 Hz signal. We understand that. How much can the time drift over the course of a year? That is key to deciding what kind of circuit you can use.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like a CMOS 7200 wristwatch chip would do what you need. According to the CMOS Cookbook, if you connect a 1.55 volt input through a 10k resistor into the TEST pin on this chip it will put out a 1 Hz square wave across the resistor. That's intended for calibrating the time, but in your application, you could skip all the other hookup to the watch and simply wire the chip to 2 1.5 volt button batteries, in series for the ~3.1V main power, and the center tap of the 2 batteries to the TEST pin.

You could then put a transistor across the 10K resistor to boost the voltage drop across the resistor to +5V, and feed that into your watch control circuit.

It looks like a [TPL5000DGST](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpl5000.pdf) programmable timer would be even better. If I read the data sheet correctly, that is an extremely low-power timer chip that is designed to output pulses at a settable interval where 1 HZ is one of the options. It looks like that chip includes a built-in oscillator. You could feed it regulated 5V input and you should get clean logic-level outputs out of it.

Disclaimer: I'm a software developer, not an EE. I'm getting this info by reading books and data sheets.